# Using types defined in class

Tags: c++, class, types

What is the most convenient and clear way to define variables of type declared inside some complex class. For example:

```
template<class T1, class T2> 
class ClassA
{
    enum ENUM_A { A1, A2 };
    //constructor
    ClassA(const ENUM_A& x);
}
```

Then when you want to use this object somewhere else, you'll have to write long type definitions like:

```
ClassA<ClassT1, ClassT2>::ENUM_A var = ClassA<ClassT1, ClassT2>::A1;
ClassA<ClassT1, ClassT2> obj(var);
```

Is there any safe and convenient way to avoid such long declarations? (I've thought about `typedef`, but maybe it)

Comment: `auto var = ClassA<ClassT1, ClassT2>::A1;`?

Comment: maybe similar to [`graph_traits`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_traits.html) in Boost.

Comment: If the nested type is used a lot, why not promote it to the top level?

Comment: @Alan: Frequent use is not a good reason to break a design.

Comment: @Lightness If a type is used in many contexts it may be a sign that it represents an independent rather than a dependent concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions have already been named: `typedef` (or `using`), and `auto` to skip naming the type entirely.

Comment: `auto` is a nice solution. As I understand there is no similar way to avoid `ClassA<ClassT1, ClassT2>::` in front of the `enum` element? For example, when the same element (say `A1`) is used for many template types of `ClassA`?

Comment: @user2028058: If it's not dependent then, yeah, I think it's time to take that `enum` out. Either up a scope level or into some abstract base class.