# Abbreviate the full name of a type defined in a class

Tags: c++

Which is the best way to avoid to write the class name when I use a type defined in a class?

For example I have a class `MyClass` where is defined a `mytype` type, out of this class I need use `mytype` and I must write:

```
MyClass::mytype foo
```

I would like to write only

```
mytype foo
```

I've try with

```
#define MyClass::mytype mytype
```

It works but I think that this is not a good solution. What should I use?

Comment: Depending on your scenario `auto my_value = ...` or `typedef MyClass::mytype mytype` or `using mytype = MyClass::mytype`, but never `#define ...`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using types defined in class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20274818/using-types-defined-in-class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
typedef MyClass::mytype mytype;
```

Comment: ha, you were faster by 15 seconds :)

Comment: And [PreferenceBean](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20274891/1139697) was two years faster :P, @MarcusMüller.

Comment: @Zeta: Well-spotted! I should have figured this was too obvious to not have been asked.

Answer (score 4):

Use a typedef or an alias declaration, ideally in the narrowest possible scope.

```
void some_function() {
    typedef MyClass::mytype mytype;
    // or: using mytype = MyClass::mytype;
}
// namespace not polluted
```